WPF Datagrid color based off SQL result
I have been trying lots of different things to change the cell color for the row that returns a "1" from a certain column. I have been hitting a brick wall on all my attempts.
Here is what I'm looking at - this is my selection if column has "1":
My xaml for the JobId if value is true.
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Suspended}" Value="Running">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEA2B0D"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
<DataGrid.Columns >
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}"  Width="40" Header=" Job ID " Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True" >
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF8A8A8A"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>


string lbcompjob = ("SELECT * FROM " + Table + "  WHERE [cancled] = 1");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(lbcompjob, conn);
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string can = dr[0].ToString();

                if (can == "1")
                {
                    // If True change row color
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}


"change the cell color for the row that returns a "1" from a certain column" - Why don't you the column? Your question doesn't share much useful information.

Without a "data object" as a source reference, it's just a guess what the propery names are. A "get" property cell binding that returns a color could put an end to all of this.

Just add a trigger to the RowStyle:
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Suspended}" Value="Running">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEA2B0D"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <!-- Add your trigger here -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyColumn}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>


So i have rebuilt it and i belive i have a conflicting issue with loading the datagrid.
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dat = new DataTable(Table);
sda.Fill(dat);
dataview.ItemsSource = dat.DefaultView;
conn.Close();
dataview.ItemsSource = cellvalue;
cellvalue.Add(new CellColor
{
cancled = Brushes.Red
});

<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="10*" Header=" Status " Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible">
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF8A8A8A"/>
     </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
              <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                   <Style.Triggers>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding cstatus}" Value="1"> // Binding to sql column ----  
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF1515"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding cancled}" Value="1"> // Binding to sql column ----  
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEC6100"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding job_completed}" Value="1"> // Binding to sql column ----  
                               <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF009802"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>

On this Example
DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status} = the row that shows on your DataGrid.
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding cstatus}" Value="1">  are the rows in your database that looks for the value.
So in this case we have a Row in our Datagrid that Is Labled Status
and if any conditions are met that row will change color to the corresponding color.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
